# Javascript/NodeJS order of execution of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am working on a full stack project that uses NodeJS for the backend and I have the following code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const pool = require("./db");

pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to PostgreSQL:', err);
    return;
  }

  client.query('SELECT 1', (queryErr, result) => {
   

    if (queryErr) {
      console.error('Error executing query:', queryErr);
    } else {
      console.log('PostgreSQL connection successful');
    }

    // Close the pool (optional)
    
  });
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("server listening on port 8080");
});
```

When I run this, the output I get is the following:

server listening on port 8080

PostgreSQL connection successful

My question is, why does the program print "server listening on port 8080" before printing "PostgresSQL connection successful"? Shouldn't it be the other way around since Javascript is executed in sequential order, from top to bottom?

Comment: Because `pool.connect` is an asynchronous operation and its callback function doesn't fire until, as the log suggests, there's an actual connection to postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Both `pool.connect` and `app.listen` are asynchronous operations., i.e., parallel operations. You will need to add `await` before asynchronous operations to make them synchronous, i.e., sequential. In essence Javascript natively is an asynchronous programming language. In this case, both function calls have arrow function as an argument, which is called a *callback*, generally. That means, once the execution of the parent function is completed, the callback function is called and executed.

Here, the `app.listen` function has executed faster than `pool.connect` and thereby its callback is executed first followed by the callback of `pool.connect`

Reference: [Callback Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)